# How to use "RVM --default" on MacOSX

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

After using Ruby and Rails for quite some time now, I wanted to try RVM. Everything works fine, except for one thing:

In a freshly opened Terminal `ruby` points to the system's ruby, despite the fact, that I used the `rvm --default` command.

```
user@terra ~ $ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin10]
user@terra ~ $ which ruby
/opt/local/bin/ruby
user@terra ~ $ rvm list
   ruby-1.8.7-p334 [ ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ ]
```

Everything is fine after I call `rvm reload`

```
user@terra ~ $ rvm reload
user@terra ~ $ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.1]
tmangner@terra ~ $ which ruby
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
```

I set up my `.bash_profile` as described in the documentation:

```
[[ -s "/Users/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

That `--default` does not seem to work for me ...

```
user@terra ~ $ rvm use 1.9.2 --default
Using /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
user@terra ~ $ rvm default
user@terra ~ $
```

I'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.6)

Comment: As @Gwilnm Kuiper's answer says, you have to specify the version to be the default also. `rvm use 1.9.2 --default` or `rvm use 1.8.7 --default`. Then, to switch Rubies do a normal, unadorned "use", `rvm 1.8.7` or `rvm 1.9.2`, or even `rvm default` to return to the default one. You can switch back to the system Ruby using `rvm use system`.

Comment: Also, be sure to periodically run `rvm get head` to update it, followed by `rvm reload` to load the changes. RVM always updates quickly, but the last couple weeks has made some big update jumps.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I had the same problem once. It turned out the rvm-script got loaded twice, which broke things a bit.

Check all the files that load when you open a shell:

```
/etc/profile
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
```

and so on, and make sure they don't load RVM twice.

Maybe put

```
echo "Going to load RVM"
```

before

```
[[ -s "/Users/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in your `~/.bash_profile` to see if it happens or not.

Comment: +1 I've seen the initializing script show up twice also, once in .bashrc and again in .bash_profile even though I'm sure I'd only added it to .bashrc. It's a mystery which I blame on the Linux elves trying to be helpful late at night. Anyway, you're correct, RVM's initializer script should be in .bashrc only.

Comment: That actually worked. My `/etc/profile` was full of RVM stuff. Possibly from a failed as-root installation of RVM (I switched to a as-user installation, later). I removed all RVM-related stuff from the `/etc/profile` and everthing works as expected.

Comment: I was searching for 1 Year now and its finally fixed. This information is still valid. If the [[..]] part is loaded multiple times the default ruby will not be loaded in the terminal.

Comment: yes, it breaks if you try to load it more than once. i also made sure that there was only one call to `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"`

Answer (score 18):

Moving the initialization

```
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in the bottom of `~/.bash_profile` solved the problem for me.

Comment: i moved this out of .bash_profile and into the bottom of .zshrc since i use zsh.

Answer (score 9):

A possible fix for ZSH users:

Somehow I had:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in both .zprofile and .zshrc.

Removing the line from .zprofile resolved the issue. (Though you should be able to remove from either, as long as it appears just once)

Answer (score 6):

Run the command:

```
rvm use --default 1.9.2?
```

This worked for me on openSUSE, I don't know about Snow Leopard though.

Comment: +1. This is necessary, otherwise RVM has NOooo idea what version of Ruby is supposed to be the default. And, the syntax is consistent across all OSes that RVM works on (Mac OS, Linux distros), though I use `rvm use 1.9.2 --default` because my normal "use" command is `rvm use 1.9.2` or `rvm use 1.8.7`.

Comment: Yeah i did that. But it doesn't helped :-(

Comment: what happens when you run 'rvm list default'?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.

Moving:

```
 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

after the line from MacPorts:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of:

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

I used the full version:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290 --default
```

That worked for me in zsh.

Comment: Type  `rvm list` to list installed versions.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and since I use [Oh-My-Zsh](http://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) it was a little bit more difficult to track if I have duplicate calls to RVM.

I fixed it by moving the call to RVM from the separate rvm.zsh file located in my `\custom` folder inside `\oh-my-zsh` to the very end of my main .zshrc file.

It looks like RVM is really sensitive to being called not at the end of your zsh initialization sequence.

Comment: Yeah, oh-my-zsh was screwing with my rvm too :)

Comment: Same problem here.  I just moved the rvm line to the bottom of .zshrc.

Comment: Bingo! RVM was putting it in my .zprofile which caused the problem.

Answer (score 5):

As a sanity check, make sure that the project you are working on has the same Ruby version that you try to set as default in the `.ruby-version` file.

It happened to me, and I couldn't figure out why `rvm` doesn't use my default.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Mac OS X 10.7, and later I found that my account was not added to the "rvm" group.

After I added myself to it I can set `--default`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to set default Ruby for a new shell:

```
sudo rvm alias create default 1.9.2
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was resolved by changing

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin
```

to

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

in my `.zshrc` file.

Obviously, you need to make sure RVM is properly installed first, and run the `type rvm | head -1` check that @choise suggested. `rvm use --default 1.9.3-p362` now works properly.

See "[Sometimes, CD to a dir with .rvmrc doesn't set the Ruby version or gemset](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1351#issuecomment-10939525)" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the path to RVM in front of your PATH:

```
$ export PATH=/path/to/rvm-dir:$PATH
```

Comment: No, if RVM has been set up correctly it will do this for him. We don't need to. See @choise's answer.

Answer (score 0):

What does `type rvm | head -1` print out?

In my `.bash_profile` on the latest MacOS X I had to put:

```
# Ruby Version Manager
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

I also created a gemset and set this as default:

```
rvm reload
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm --create use 1.9.2@default
rvm --default use 1.9.2@default
```

Comment: rvm is a function ... no problem on that.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I had in my `$HOME/bin` directory `ruby`, `gem`, `rake`, ... file stubs.  Therefore my `rvm --default use 1.9.3` didn't work as expected. Removing the `$HOME/bin` directory solved the problem.

```
cat  bin/ruby 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p290" ]]
then
  source "/usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
  exec ruby "$@"
else
  echo "ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p290'" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For some really newbies on Mac OS use JewelryBox and in preferences section you find

```
"show default ruby in system menu bar"
```

checking this allow you to switch between rubies.

You can select your pre-installed rubygems (if you have rubygems) via "system@*" choice.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the suggestions above - checked my bash_profile (which was fine) and also noticed that in ubuntu you may need to head the advice of https://rvm.io/support/faq/#shell_login

However I was still having this problem until I realised that the project I was trying to run had a .rvmrc file that was specifying a version of ruby that I didn't have installed. When I corrected this - I stopped having the problem (so in fact it wasn't that the use default wasn't working, but that this project was overriding it)

Comment: Instead of "https://rvm.io/support/faq/#shell_login" perhaps you meant "[What shell login means ('bash -l')](https://rvm.io/support/faq#what-shell-login-means-bash-l)"?

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the `[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"` line from ~/.bash_profile and had to move it to the very bottom of ~/.bashrc.

This fixed the issue on OS X 10.10.1.