# Problem with system-wide RVM install

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

I installed the Ruby EE as my system-wide Ruby.

I added:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

at the end of /etc/profile.

```
if [ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ] ; then
  . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
fi
```

then

```
rvm install ree
rvm --default ree
```

I did my logoff and login, and I'm able to check `ruby -v`, and it's right, ree is my default Ruby.

The problem is, I install my gems, e.g `gem install bundle`, and then try to run bundler and it is not found. If I run the command one more time, `rvm use ree`, then I'm able to run bundler.

My RVM info:

```
web:~# rvm info

system:

system:
uname:       "Linux web 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5.028stab089.1 #1 SMP Thu Apr 14 14:06:01 MSD 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
zsh:         " => not installed"

rvm:
   version:      "rvm 1.6.5 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com)[https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

homes:
gem:          "not set"
ruby:         "not set"

binaries:
ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby"
irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/bin/irb"
gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem"
rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rake"

environment:
PATH:         "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin"
GEM_HOME:     ""
GEM_PATH:     ""
MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
IRBRC:        ""
RUBYOPT:      ""
gemset:       ""
```

added extra infos

```
web:~# rvm list

rvm rubies

   ree-1.8.7-2011.03 [ x86_64 ]

web:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
web:~# gem list | grep bundle
bundler (1.0.12)
web:~# gem list | grep bundler
bundler (1.0.12)
web:~# bundle
-bash: bundle: command not found
web:~# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03
web:~#
```

Comment: I think your keyboard ran out of capital letters. :-)

Comment: Any file listed by `gem which bundler`? Also, the command is called `bundle`, not `bundler`. I don't know if you have typos in your question or are actually using the gem called `bundle` instead of `gem install bundler`.

Comment: whats the output of `rvm list` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cause: i had in two different init scripts the source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"

this answer helped me to find my way [Why doesn't "RVM --default" work for me on MacOSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604877/why-doesnt-rvm-default-work-for-me-on-macosx)