# Foreman will not start with Unicorn

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, unicorn, foreman

I'm trying to get Foreman to work with my Unicorn setup.

Here is my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

Here is the output when I start Foreman:

```
10:41:37 web.1     | started with pid 19300
10:41:38 web.1     | /Users/seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
10:41:38 web.1     | process terminated
10:41:38 web.1     |    from /Users/seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2
10:41:38 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
10:41:38 web.1     |    from /Users/seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1:in
```

It's failing on:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

UPDATE: After a quick sanity check by running *ruby --version* I realize I was actually running 1.8.7.  For some reason running *rvm use --default 1.9.2-p136* or even the newly installed 1.9.2-p320 does not persist after I close that terminal window.  It always reverts back to 1.8.7.

So I was able to start foreman now but when I close that terminal and come back I'm back to 1.8.7, any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you specify the GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME in *.env*?

Comment: They are:  GEM_HOME=/Users/seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136 GEM_PATH=/Users/seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136:/Users/seth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global

Comment: But what happens when you add them to the *.env* file?

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything, same result.

Comment: I suppose I could get rid of RVM, I don't even need it anymore. I can't think of anything else that would affect it.

Comment: Where is the stack trace? How does it fail? What are the messages?

Comment: I added the complete output the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving this line:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

To the bottom of my .profile fix it for me. This helped me: [Why doesn't "RVM --default" work for me on MacOSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604877/why-doesnt-rvm-default-work-for-me-on-macosx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running login session to make RVM run in interactive mode - for example: https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ or https://rvm.io/workflow/screen/

but for using RVM in scripting you should read: https://rvm.io/integration/cron/