# How to make RVM use the default automatically

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, ubuntu-14.04

RVM doesn't use the default Ruby version on both my Mac and Ubuntu server.

This is what I get when I do `rvm list` on my Mac:

```
rvm rubies

 * ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

And what I get on Ubuntu:

```
rvm rubies

 * ruby-2.1.2 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

They are already the default and only version available, but I have to manually type `rvm use 2.1.2` each time when I need to do some Ruby stuff. I guess I could put that command into `.profile` or the like, but it feels hackish since I'm expecting RVM to use the *default* version.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Did you set the default ruby using this command `rvm use ruby-2.1.2 --default` ?

Comment: Did you run `rvm --default use 2.1.2` to set and use the ruby 2.1.2 as default?

Comment: Yes I've already tried `rvm use ruby-2.1.2 --default`. But closing and starting another shell causes ruby to default back to system's ruby.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11105199/1896986 and run the command `rvm --default use 2.1.2` once.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved the problem.

I tried `rvm use ruby-2.1.2 --default` multiple times and it didn't work.  There's two things I did:

1. I moved this line:

   ```
   [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
   ```

   in `~/.bash_profile` to the last line. See "[How to use "RVM --default" on MacOSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604877/how-to-use-rvm-default-on-macosx/14782792#14782792)".

   Somehow some application decided to add itself to this file and making it the first in the path.
2. Run `rvm get head`.

This solved the problem for me on my Mac.