# RVM not running proper ruby version

Tags: ruby, terminal, rvm

I've installed ruby version 2.1.3 but it is not being loaded as the default Ruby version when a new terminal window is created. Even stranger, a version I dont have listed as being installed is being listed as the default version of ruby when a new terminal window is open.

```
   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.3 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Is what I see when I switch to 2.1.3 in a new terminal window.

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

Is what I see in a new window. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To set the default to the version you wish to use you can do the following...

```
rvm --default use 2.1.3
```

Editing to reflect comment:

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604877/why-doesnt-rvm-default-work-for-me-on-macosx) is your issue...

Comment: Thanks. I've put in this command in before posting to SO but new terminal windows still open with ruby 2.0.0. Not sure why.