# How to tell RVM (Ruby Version Manager) to remember my set default when I open a new terminal window

Tags: ruby, rvm

I used RVM to install Ruby 2.5.1, and set that to the default. However when I open a new terminal window, and type `which ruby` I get the path to my machine's Ruby not the one I set.

For example, when I set the default and run `which ruby`:

```
=> /home/COM-COM/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
```

When I open a new terminal window and run `which ruby`:

```
=> /usr/bin/ruby
```

I thought when I ran `rvm --default use 2.5.1` RVM would remember the set default until I changed it.

Does anyone know what's going on here, and does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't "RVM --default" work for me on MacOSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604877/why-doesnt-rvm-default-work-for-me-on-macosx)

Comment: What about `rvm --default 2.5.1`?

Comment: @tadman The command `rvm --default use 2.5.1` is supposed to set that version of ruby to be the system's default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install a specific version of Ruby (2.5.1), you can use this:

```
rvm install ruby-2.5.1
rvm --default use ruby-2.5.1
```

If you wanted to install and use the latest version of Ruby, you can use the following:

```
rvm install ruby
rvm --default use ruby
```