# How to set a default version of Ruby on OSX/Ubuntu using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ubuntu, rvm

I installed Ruby v2.6.3 via RVM on my laptop for a Rails application.

To activate it I ran:

```
rvm --default use 2.6.3
```

However, if I restart my macOS laptop and check the current version of Ruby using `rvm list`, then the old v2.3.3 version is set.

How do I permanently set the version "2.6.3" as the one to use? The same thing occurs on Ubuntu, when I deploy a Rails application, the Ruby version automatically reverts back to v2.3.3 instead of v2.6.3.

---

```
rvm list
   ruby-2.2.3 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.3 [ x86_64 ]
```

---

I noticed that after restarting my laptop, `rvm list` looks a bit different:

```
   ruby-2.2.3 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.1 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.6.3 [ x86_64 ]
```

Now,  version 2.6.3 is automatically set as the default, however the current version 2.3.3 is still selected.

Comment: What does `rvm list` show?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev added.

Comment: so it shows that default and current version of ruby is 2.3.3. I suppose something wrong with PATH. Have you read this topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604877/how-to-use-rvm-default-on-macosx

Comment: Based on the update you posted, I would assume that you have changed into a directory that has a `.ruby-version` file that is changing your current version of Ruby.

Comment: I've added this line: `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` to the `~/.zshrc` file. However, still investigating what happened and why is not automatically used `2.6.3` and only `2.3.3` (the Rails app doesn't work on 2.3.3.)

Comment: Do the following in order and post the output of each command: close all open shells/terminals; open a new terminal; `rvm list`; `ruby -v`; `ls .ruby-version`; `rvm --default use 2.6.3`; `rvm list`; `ruby -v`; then repeat all previous steps.

Comment: Please do _not_ use "edit" or "update" tags to mark changes. Instead, simply incorporate the change as if it'd been there all along, writing for readability and to make sense. We can tell what changed and when if necessary.

Comment: Please run `rvm info`, copy the output then paste it into your question, formatting it appropriately for readability.